# ORA-01438: on 6 digit number

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting the error:

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this
>   column

My column definition is

```
MO_AZN_AMT   NOT NULL NUMBER(8,3)
```

and I'm trying to insert **262622** in it?

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Datatype:    `NUMBER(8,3)`

```
8 - total length
3 - fractional part
```

Can store `XXXXX.YYY`

```
8 - 3 = 5 digits for integer part
262622 > 99999
```

You need to alter your column to support it like `NUMBER(12,3)`.